# BizTalk 2010 Prevent output of Property Schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an orchestration which is receiving messages from the message box of type XmlDocument. The messages have promoted properties and I am including the property schema in my project so that I may filter on them (a separate application is creating these messages). I am then assigning the untyped message to a typed message (I am not altering the name space) via a standard message assignment shape e.g.

```
MsgAgressoNewStarters = MsgXmldoc;
```

I am then outputting the message to a file location.  However when I do this the property schema is also outputted.

How can I prevent this? I have tried filters etc.

Thanks

10th May 2012

I think I am possibly going about this the wrong way perhaps if I describe the full scenario you may be able to spot my deliberate mistake ;)

We are using BizTalk 2010.

I have a BizTalk application which talks to a 3rd party generic webservice that returns reports from one of our systems.  This application is activated via the scheduled adapter which sends an XML document containing two values, the report name and the interface it is for.  The web service returns the report as a string on a single XML node, this string in its self is an XML document.  I then load this string into a message of type System.Xml.XmlDocument.  There is no way of telling from the format of the data what report or for what interface this message is for.  I need to send this message to the messagebox for it to be picked up by any number of related biztalk applications.  So far I have tried creating a correlation set with the two values (from a property schema) & used that as the initialising correlation set on the send shape.  I have then used the same property schema on another BT application to filter the message.  This works but for some reason I get two messages, one being the XML which activities the orchestration which has the same fields as  the property schema & correlation set.  BizTalk doesn't seem to be able to tell the difference between them although they are structurally different and this is where my problem starts.

I am now thinking of creating a multipart message in the report application one part being the XmlDocument and the other being a header with the values I wish to route on.

Hope that makes some kind of sense.

Comment: How are you outputting the message? This seems like it should work and I'm surprised you're getting the message context too.

Comment: Yes but it fails, both are outputted at the same time with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually now answered my own question, because both messages have the same properties I am inadvertently subscribing to both, d'oh!

Comment: good spot! I noticed the "Agresso" string as part of your message. Are you integrating with ABW? :-)